# Can Hyperledger-fabric samples be hosted in Windows 10 Home edition?

Tags: windows, docker, hyperledger-fabric

I get errors while building your first network

I was able to run this command `./byfn.sh generate` and can see peers and orderer generated.

With the command `./byfn.sh up` I get the following error:

> ERROR: SSL error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) ERROR !!!! Unable to start network.

Comment: Have you tried all the steps from the tutorial? http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/prereqs.html

Comment: Yes, insipte, I got this error.

Comment: OK. I'm sorry, I don't know why it appears. If I were you, I'll try to build your firts network in a Virtual Machine inside your Windows 10 PC